# Finding CGPoint by adding into distance of two CGPoints

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, cgpoint, box2d-iphone, ios-4.2

I have two CGPoints A and B. Distance between A and B can be found with ccpDistance(A,B).

With this information, I need to find programmatically CGPoint(x,y) of X by adding small distance into distance of A-B. A-B may can make a connecting line in horizontal, vertical, diagonal or any orientation. Purpose is to extend the imaginary line and find a point at the end of it.

Is it possible in Box2D for iOS? If Yes, then how?

```
          X            Y   X
         /               .  \ 
        /                  . \
       B                     .B
      /                        \
     /                          \
    /                            \
   /                              \
  A                                A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following function (put it in one of your `.h` files):

```
static inline CGPoint
ccpLineExtend(const CGPoint v1, const CGPoint v2, const CGFloat extension)
{
    double angle = atan2(v2.y - v1.y, v2.x - v1.x);
    return ccp(v2.x + extension * cos(angle), v2.y + extension * sin(angle));
}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much. It works like charm for the first figure. It is not considering reverse angle like in figure 2. It is giving Y point at dotted distance. I so much hope you can provide solution for this one too.

Comment: @WJK: Are you sure you calculated it right? Because a simple test of `ccpLineExtend(ccp(3, 0), ccp(0, 4), 5.0)` gives the correct `-3.0, 8.0` .. the trigonometric formula can't be wrong. Oh yeah, if you want to use it in Box2D, don't forget to divide both x and y components by PTM_RATIO

Comment: You are right. It's straight trigonometry. It is only happening to me for angle between 90-135 degrees. May be because I have load many calculations, so some value might be impacting it. Thanks.

Comment: some other value was affecting lineExtend, it's solved now. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following method which doesn't make use of any triangular function. I suppose it's faster than Lukman's suggestion but I didn't measure times.

```
static inline CGPoint ccpLineExtend(const CGPoint from, const CGPoint to, const CGFloat factor)
{
    return CGPointMake(from.x + factor * (to.x - from.x), from.y + factor * (to.y - from.y));
}
```

`factor = 1.0` means that the resulting point is equal to point `to`. `factor = 2.0` means that the resulting point is as twice as far from `from` as `to` is.

Answer (score 0):

@Lars's answer was best and simplest for me. Here is the Swift 4 version:

```
let newPoint = CGPoint(x: origin.x + factor * (end.x - origin.x), y: origin.y + factor * (end.y - origin.y))
```

If you have the current distance, you can add and subtract from it or change it altogether by calculating:

```
let factor = newDistance/currentDistance
```

In my case, I had a distance calculator from CGPoint to CGPoint using an extension:

```
extension CGPoint {
    func distance(to point: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
        let x = self.x - point.x
        let y = self.y - point.y
        return sqrt(pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2))
    }
}
```